# is SAT as set of satisfiable formulas in FOL recursive or recursive enumerable ?

Tags: computability

Can somebody help to understand whether SAT as the set of satisfiable formulas of first-order classical logic. Is SAT recursive, r.e. or none of them?

Thank you so much

Comment: See [Satisfiability in first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability#Satisfiability_in_first-order_logic).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you :)